# Kal calendar month not showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, kal

Here is the link to the github https://github.com/phaibin/Kal

This is what it is suppose to look like
[image]

However this is what I am getting
[image]

Here are the codes
.h file:
    #import

```
@class KalViewController;

@interface Planner_Calendar : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>{
    KalViewController *kal;
    id dataSource;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *calendarView;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "EventKitDataSource.h"
#import "Kal.h"
#import "NSDate+Convenience.h"
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@implementation Planner_Calendar
@synthesize calendarView;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    kal = [[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectionMode:KalSelectionModeSingle];
    kal.selectedDate = [NSDate dateStartOfDay:[NSDate date]];

    kal.title = @"NativeCal";
    kal.delegate = self;
    dataSource = [[EventKitDataSource alloc] init];
    kal.dataSource = dataSource;

    [self.calendarView addSubview:kal.view];
}

@end
```

Comment: If you remember your question, call us, will you?

Comment: The question is the month and year is not showing on the 2nd bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem Add Localizable.strings file  to Your Project

you can get this file [From Here](https://github.com/phaibin/Kal/tree/master/Examples/NativeCal/en.lproj)

To Add it

File ---> Add Files to "your Project name"

[image]

the file contain

```
"CalendarTitle"     = "LLLL yyyy";
```

if your already have this file , then just add this line of code

if you dont have it its ok

Go to File > New > File. Choose Strings File unders the Resource subsection as shown below:

[image]

Click Next, name the file Localizable.strings, then click Save.

write inside it `"CalendarTitle"     = "LLLL yyyy";`

Answer (score 0):

Just have to add localization string to the application and it will solve this problem